# Eclipse Marketplace Not Showing All Search Results

Tags: linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-mars, eclipse-marketplace

I'm having an issue with the eclipse marketplace where doing a search doesn't show all available results. Searching for "java" I get a list of about 10 available plugins and at the bottom it says *"156 matches. Browse for more solutions."*

[image]

The problem is, when I click to browse more solutions I just get a blank emacs window and I can't seem to get to any of the other search results so I'm stuck with only the first 10 options.

**How can I get it to show the rest of the results?**

I'm running eclipse on a RedHat 6 Linux server and using a Cygwin XWindow to open it on my PC. My eclipse version info is below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When clicking on that link, Eclipse should be opening your web browser. Somehow, on your system, Eclipse thinks that Emacs is your web browser. You can fix this on your system set-up, or override that system settings in Eclipse for Eclipse only.

### Set Default Browser

1. Open Preferences
2. Navigate to General -> Web Browser
3. Customize your settings

[image: web browswer preferences screenshot]

### Visit Marketplace Directly

An alternative is to browse to the Eclipse Marketplace directly in your web browser:

- https://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/java

Comment: This seems like it may be the problem, the terminal server I am using doesn't appear to have a browser installed. I will look further into it. Thanks!